# Localized app choosing the wrong images

Tags: ios, image, localization

I localized my app and when I open it I get the english version. (Default is german language). I thought that I could copy the images with english text into the en.lproj folder. (They are the same name as the german versions). But it still takes the images from the de.lproj folder. And yes, running in german or english both work fine, only the images do not appear to change. 
I did not set the images programmatically, but rather arranged them in the view (*.xib).

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem. This seems like a bug in IB. If I rename one of loc. folders (eg. en.lproj) and then trying to open 'name.xib' Czech/English I see sometimes czech version of image, sometimes it shows missing one.

Comment: Here is what I did: Made a snapshot. Deleted the XIBs. Cleaned the project. Made new xibs. Arranged everything again. Cleaned it. And then it worked. Also try it on your device and see if it works there correctly.